# Performance logging

Tags: mfc, c++17, database-performance, windows-server-2008-r2, reportserver

I have an MFC application and the application interact with the database(SQL) heavily.
We also have the functionality of exporting SSRS reports.

I am working on improving the logs, what information can I put to see if the windows server/ database server/ report server was functioning at their desired performance level.
We often get the complaint from the client regarding the slow application but having so many entities involved I find it hard to pinpoint the problem area

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for this question.

Comment: Actually, SSRS and SQL Server database performance problems should be evaluated in the different approaches. In my thought, this question is very general and should need more detail in order to handle your performance issues.  Such as, you can check long-running reports in the ReportServer database with help of the ExecutionLog2 or ExecutionLog3. On the other hand, sys.dm_exec_query_stats will help to identify the long-running queries in the SQL Server. Therefore , we need more details about your issue.